# Can method call be tested without Mockito.verify?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito

If i need to test if a method within *class under test* has been called or not, can it be done without Mockito (or any mocking tool for that matter)?

Reason asking is that wherever i read about Mockito and similar tools, it says one should never mock CUT but its dependencies (that part is clear).

So, if thats the case then there are only 2 options left:

1. there is some other way of testing it without mocking

or

2. the fact the method was called should not be tested itself but some side effect or methods return value

For example (trivial and non-realworld), class `MyClass` can have 2 methods: `A()` and `B()`. A conditionay calls B based on some internal state.
After arranging state & acting by calling `A()` we want to assert that `B()` was called.
Either its not possible without mocking the whole CUT or 2 methods like this in a single class are always SRP violation smell and call for redesign where `B()` should actually be (mocked) dependency of `MyClass` CUT.

So, whats correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I tend to not even use spies, instead I prefer to write my code in a way that for any class I write:

- I test only non-private methods, since they're entry points into the class under test. So, in your example, if a() calls b(), maybe b() should be be private and, as a consequence, should not be tested. To generalize, a() is something that a class "can do" (a behavior), so I test the behavior, and not the method itself. If this behavior internally calls other things - well, its an internal matter of that class, if possible I don't make any assumptions on how does the class work internally, and always prefer "white-box" testing. 
  I only test "one" non-private method in a test.
- All the methods should return something (best option) or at least call dependencies, or change internal state of the object under test. The list of dependencies is always clean-to-understand, I can't instantiate the object of CUT without supplying it a list of dependencies. For example, using constructor dependency injection is a good way of doing this. I mock only dependencies indeed, and never mock / spy CUT. Dependencies are never static but injected.

Now with these simple rules, the need to "*test if a method within class under test has been called or not*" basically can boil down to one of the following:

- you're talking about private method. In this case - don't test it, test only public things.
- The method is public - in this case you explicitly call it in unit test, so its irrelevant.

Now lets ask **why** do you want to *test this if a method within CUT has been called or not*?

If you want to make sure that it changed something. If this "something" is within the class - in other words, its internal state has changed, check in test that the change is indeed done in the state by calling another method that allows to query the state
If this "something" is a code that is managed by dependency, create a mock of this dependency and verify that it was called with the expected parameters.

Comment: thank you for some very good points! what you are saying actually confirms that calling `Mock.verify` on CUTs method could be a good indication of code smell since that method (assuming its public) should either be dependency (mocked), have a side effect of changing CUTs state (then test state) or return something (call directly from test and assert result).

Comment: thanks for clarification, that makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Mockito Documentation (https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13)

When using a `Spy` you can 'replace' a method in the same class that is under test.

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class Test {

    class MyClass {

        public void a() {
            b();
        }

        public void b() {

        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {

        MyClass testClass = new MyClass();
        MyClass spy = Mockito.spy(testClass);

        Mockito.doNothing().when(spy).b();

        spy.a();

        Mockito.verify(spy, Mockito.times(1)).b();
    }   
}
```

So whether that is something that should be done is a different question ;)
I think it highly depends on what method B() is actually doing and whether that is supposed be part of MyClass in the first place.

---

> Either its not possible without mocking the whole CUT

In this case we do not mock the whole CUT only the method you do not want to be called.

---

> Reason asking is that wherever i read about Mockito and similar tools, it says one should never mock CUT but its dependencies (that part is clear).

I believe this statement is not entirely accurate in correlation with spying.
The whole point of spying in my eyes is to use it on the class under test. Why would one want to spy on a dependecy that is not even supposed to be part of the test in the first place?

Comment: thanks for your reply! yes, i am aware of `mockito.[mock|spy].verify(...)`. So, i know it can be done that way, question is more about: is there non-mocking way of doing it and/or should it be done at all?;)

Comment: well, i might be wrong but isn’t `Mockito.spy(testClass)` mocking (ok, spying, but same thing) CUT and then stubbing its `B()` method?

Comment: I guess that depends on what you want to express with the word `mocking`. Normally I would read `mocking` as `replace` or `stub`.

Comment: For your other question. I think it highly depends on what `method B()` is actually doing and whether that is supposed be part of `MyClass` in the first place.

Comment: well, thats a good question. i guess my confusion comes from many places where i read *one should not mock CUT* but its dependencies. The way i read it was that one should not use `Mockito.[mock|spy](CUT)` ever except when having 3rd party dependencies (without DI) so when one need to stub a method within `MyClass`. That would be like in your example. Furthermore, i read it like in this scenario, `B()` should actually be extracted to new class which would be injected in `MyClass` as dependency and then mock that new class. So, am i reading it wrong?

Comment: If we go with that interpretation why would `spy` even exist? It makes no sense to `spy` on a dependency, as its not supposed to be part of the `unit that is under test`.

Comment: In my understanding, we would not spy third party but we would spy `MyClass` in order to be able to stub its method (which uses 3rd party something). Just imagine `B()` internally calls 3rd party something. That would, in my understanding, be a case for your test example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197244/discussion-between-second-and-dee-zg).